# Why can I not change the value that is target of on options binding?

Tags: knockout.js

How is it possible, that is can not change the value of an observable bound to the value attribute of an options binding? ... I have this html:

```
<select id="32" data-bind="value : vm.selectedControl,'optionsCaption' : GetFormControlAttribute('32316'),'options' : vm.formControlsView.rows(),'optionsText' : function(item){[...]}></select>
```

...which displays perfectly fine and does what it shall, but the problem is that as soon as I do this in my javascript code:

```
vm.selectedControl(vm.formControlsView.rowById(formControlId));
```

...nothing happens, meaning the value in vm.selectedControl does not change and stays with what was last set using the select element. What can I do to make to options binding not be so persistent about the value it last set and accept the new value set by my javascript code?

btw.: I do not have any subscriptions to vm.selectedControl that set it back to the old value.

Any hints are appreciated

Comment: You will need to provide a [repro](http://sscce.org) for us to be able to conveniently help you. You can edit your question to add it, even include a Stack Snipppet (it's on the toolbar) which will greatly increase your chances for help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `vm.selectedControl(value)` to set the selected option. Make sure that you are setting the value to a value that exists in the options. Here is a quick demo showing how to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wk7dr/14/